# Stream movie on desktop

Tags: delphi, video-streaming, multimedia

I have a movie file and i want to stream it on the desktop like VLC Player ( http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/18167/set-a-video-as-your-desktop-wallpaper-with-vlc/ ).

How can i achieve this in Delphi ?

Comment: There was some information about Delphi wrappers for interfacing the VLC dll in this article in [ADUG](http://members.adug.org.au/2011/12/19/delphi-headers-now-available-for-vlc/).

Comment: If you don't actually want to use VLC to accomplish this, but rather want to find a way to do this in delphi yourself, then say so explicitly.  If you did want that, I'd vote to close as unanswerable. Do you really want to decode mp4 video in delphi without a third party video codec library? Ha.

Comment: @WarrenP i don't need a video codec to decode a file that can be played inside of delphi i didn't specify all types of media files. I want to use VLC but i didn't see any answer that could help me achieve this because the VLC activeX has no property in this matter.

Comment: Using the VCL activeX might not have such a property right now, indeed. But it might well have a command line parameter. So try that then.

Answer (score 2):

As shown here, use [VLC via ActiveX](http://wiki.videolan.org/ActiveX/Delphi) to run it inside your application.  To make it output to the desktop, I would look for ActiveX component properties that would let you redirect as shown in your link.

Answer (score 0):

Shell out to use VLC.

Don't re-invent the wheel unless you need a square one.

Comment: That will require my users to have VLC installed and i don't want that

Comment: Well, since VLC is open-source, just embed it in your application (or at least the parts you need). Then they don't have to actually have it installed. In any case, re-use as much as you can, since then it's code you don't have to write and support.

Comment: Does VLC have command line parameters that could be used to do the redirection to the desktop?

Comment: @WarrenP, I don't know off the top of my head, but the VLC GUI is just a UI on top of a very powerful engine, and since it started in the Linux world, I would be _very_ surprised if there is _anything_ that can't be done from the command line for VLC.

Comment: @cdeszaq That quote's better than my "You don't have to jump 100 feet over a 3 foot hurdle"

Comment: @cdeszaq Any ideea how can i achive this kind of streaming using Delphi and VLC ?

Comment: Nope, not a clue. I have very little experience with Delphi, but I would choose the simplest integration strategy. I know the idea of requiring your users to have VLC in order to use this feature is not appealing to you, but if simply calling command-line parameters out to configure VLC is the simplest (which I expect it is), do what is fastest and simplest to implement right now and get user feedback on it. Then you have a baseline to improve on _if needed_.

Comment: If you don't want your users to have to install VLC then add its core files to your own installer. Easy and done.